# Is there any easy way to set several bits in a row within a short or int?

Tags: java

I am trying to find an easy way of setting several bits within an integer or a short value.

For a short value I want to set 5 bits, starting at bit number 6.
The value I want to set is a certain value I can store in a byte or short or whatever.

For the Java SetBits, I do not see anything where you can do something like this.
It seems like there should be an easy to do this.

Does anybody know of an easy way of doing this besides setting one bit at a time or something like that?

Comment: You're looking for bitwise operators: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. That will work for what I need to do but I was hoping there built Java method or method somebody developed, where you have a method like this       setBits(bitOffset,numbits,ValueToSet,OriginalValue)

Comment: What you want is `|`.

Comment: If you want the method, write it.  This is not a "Write my code for me" site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is to use the bitwise operations.  For example, assuming the bits are numbered from the right starting with zero, this sets 5 bits to ones starting at offset 6.

```
int target = ...
target = target | 0x07b0;  // that is 00000 0111 1100 0000
```

or if you are using Java 8:

```
target = target | 0b00000 0111 1100 0000;
```

If you want to set the same bits to value that you get from a variable, then ...

```
int target = ...
int value = ...
int temp = target & ( ~ 0b00000 0111 1100 0000 ); // clear current bit values
target = temp & ( value << 6 );  // set the new values.
```

Code involving low-level bit fiddling is messy and opaque, but the logic of the biwise operators (and the shift operators) is simple.  If you are doing this in production code, then I strongly recommend that you define a bunch of constants with semantically relevant names and use them instead of integers.

---

> I was hoping there was a builtin Java method ...

There isn't one, AFAIK.  But you could easily code and test your own bit manipulation methods, if you think it would make your coding simpler.  (The issue is that such an API probably would not improve code readability ... and the resulting code is likely to be harder for the JIT compiler to optimize.)

Comment: Wasn't me, but I'm often tempted to downvote code replies to "Write my code for me" questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary literals in Java:

```
// An 8-bit 'byte' value:
byte aByte = (byte)0b00100001;

// A 16-bit 'short' value:
short aShort = (short)0b1010000101000101;

// Some 32-bit 'int' values:
int anInt1 = 0b10100001010001011010000101000101;
int anInt2 = 0b101;
int anInt3 = 0B101; // The B can be upper or lower case.

// A 64-bit 'long' value. Note the "L" suffix:
long aLong = 0b1010000101000101101000010100010110100001010001011010000101000101L;
```

More [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html)